# Any ideas how to modify my code to display multiple choices based on 'QuestionOrder' ID?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Per code below, I used to display questions and their associated multiple choice options based on QuestionId with these 2 lines of code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>'></asp:Label>
<strong>)</strong>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label></td>
```

and everything would display correctly.

Problem with this is that the questions are not ordering correctly.

For instance, there are several surveys; Employee Survey, Salary Survey, Training Survey, etc.

With `QuestionId`, if I create a question based on Employee Survey, the first question is has `questionId` #1, the second question, `questionId` #2.

If I decide to create questions based on Salary survey, the first question would start with `questionId` #3, instead of starting over with `questionId` #1 and so on.

To allow each question to survey start its question from #1, I added another field called `questionOrder`.

This allows each survey to starts its question from #1.

I am able to accomplish this with this stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addQuestion](@surveyID INT, @question VARCHAR(255), @AnswerType CHAR(1), @CorrectAnswer NVARCHAR(50))
AS
DECLARE @qnum INT

SELECT @qnum = ISNULL(MAX(QuestionOrder),0)+1
FROM SurveyQuestions WHERE SurveyID = @surveyID

INSERT INTO SurveyQuestions(SurveyID, Question, AnswerType,CorrectAnswer,QuestionOrder)
VALUES (@SurveyID, @Question, @AnswerType,@CorrectAnswer,@qnum)
```

Then I use this on my markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>'></asp:Label>
<strong>)</strong>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label></td>
```

Problem is that now, only the questions display but not the multiple choices.

Do you know what I need to modify to fix this?

I am not sure if this is a SQL issue or .net issue.

I will post additional code if asked.

Thanks a lot in advance

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM SurveyQuestions where surveyId = @SurveyId">
   <SelectParameters>
   <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="SurveyId" Type="Int32" Name="SurveyId" DefaultValue="0" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLChoicesDataSouce" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT Title From Survey WHERE SurveyId = @SurveyId">
   <SelectParameters>
   <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="SurveyId" Type="Int32" Name="SurveyId" DefaultValue="0" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You are showing the query to insert a new question but could you show the query used to display all questions? You may also keep the state of the current question a user is on, if so could you show that sql query?

Comment: @BenAnderson, sure. I have posted it above. You can see that `Select Title from survey where surveyId = @surveyid` display the survey that questions belong to. The then the one that selects from surveyQuestion is the one that you are asking for. Thanks a lot

I have to go run an errand for about an hour. So, please give me sometime to get back with you should have additional question or recommendations.

Comment: I dont think we are going down the correct route. The issue is "All questions display but the multiple choice ones". The code you posted has to do with displaying the current question. You must somehow keep the state of which question they are on and which one they will have next. I would advise reviewing that logic

Comment: @BenAnderson, with the last code update I made, if I change the QuestionOrder to QuestionId below, then each question displays questionId, the question and the multiple choice for that question.

`<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>'></asp:Label>`

like:

1) Are you satisfied with the training?

So, I am obviously missing something.